# Pandas: the last line of `df.dtypes` is `dtype: object`, what does that mean, whose type it is?

Tags: python, pandas

This code constructs a simple DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]])
df.dtypes
```

the output is

```
0    int64
1    int64
dtype: object
```

the last line of the output is `dtype: object`, what does that mean, whose type it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means `Series` returned of `df.dtypes` has dtype `object`, because at least obne types of Series is `object` here `<class 'numpy.dtype'>`:

```
s1 = df.dtypes
print (s1.dtype)
object

print (type(s1))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

If want test of types each element of `Series`:

```
print (s1.apply(type))
MPG                                         <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Cylinders                                   <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Displacement                                <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Horsepower                                  <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Weight                                      <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Acceleration                                <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Year                                        <class 'numpy.dtype'>
Origin          <class 'pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.CategoricalD...
dtype: object
```

If test only integer `Series` it return `int64` and also is displayed this information under data of `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2])
print (s)
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64

print (s.dtype)
int64
```